# Read text injected into HTML by a Chrome extension in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I'm trying to use Selenium to read text injected by a Chrome Extension. The text is being injected as expected but I cannot figure out how to make the Selenium test to wait for the div to show up and then save the inner text to a variable. What am I missing?

Currently the console.log is returning "Promise { < pending> }"

Snippets:

Chrome Extension Content Script-

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.id = "selenium-container";
    var node = document.createTextNode(request.queryParameters);
    para.appendChild(node);

    window.document.body.appendChild(para);

});
```

Selenium Test Script -

```
async function Test() {
    
    let driver = builder
                    .forBrowser('chrome')
                    .withCapabilities({
                        'browserName': 'chrome',
                        'chromeOptions':
                        {
                            binary: '...',
                            args: [],
                            extensions: ['...']
                        }
                    })
                    .setChromeOptions(options)
                    .build();

    // Tests

    await driver.get('URL-HERE');

    const seleniumContainerElement = By.id("selenium-container");

    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(seleniumContainerElement, 10000))
                .then( (seleniumContainerElement) => {
                    console.log(seleniumContainerElement.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
                });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got working:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('selenium-container')), 10000, 'Could not locate element');
await driver.findElement(By.id('selenium-container')).getText().then(function(text) {
       console.log("Query: ", text);
    });
```